# How can I install go-ethereum on CentOS?

Tags: go-ethereum, installation

I'd like to setup go-ethereum on centos6.5. However,[this reference](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum) doesn't show how to install go-ethereum on centos.

I tried `[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ bash <(curl -L https://install-geth.ethereum.org)`, but it returned the following error. Could you tell me how to solve it?

```
==> Looking for geth
 ✘  Geth is missing

==> Checking dependencies
 ✘  apt-get is missing

==> Installation failed
==> OS not supported: geth one-liner currently support OS X, Ubuntu and Debian.
For instructions on installing ethereum on other platforms please visit http://ethereum.org/
```

Comment: i have used this tutorial for mining: http://altcoinslisting.com/blog/mine-with-centos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they chose .deb packages (Ubuntu/Debian) because they are the most common. You could always check out the latest stable version and compile it yourself though.

An easier way might be to use alien to convert the debs into rpms.

The below is completely untested.

```
yum install golang
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu/pool/main/e/ethereum/geth_1.3.3+5wily-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo alien -r geth_1.3.3+5wily-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rpm -i geth_1.3.3+5wily-0ubuntu1_amd64.rpm
```

If you want to try to compile it, it would be more like: (also untested)

```
yum install golang
yum install gmp-devel
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
cd go-ethereum
make geth
build/bin/geth
```

Answer (score 5):

Geth is a single binary executable. No other files are needed for it, so using a package manager will only get you potential updates, but you could just grab the Linux binary itself and run it straight on your machine.

We always upload Linux x64 binaries to our [GitHub releases](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases) if you would like to use the stable branch and we also provide [cross builds](https://bintray.com/karalabe/ethereum/geth-develop/view) to all platforms for our develop branch. These cross builds are done nightly and announced every morning by the build bot on out [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum) (e.g. the [last announcement](https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum?at=56c7fd72e1786831677c2697)).

Feel free to grab the plain Linux binary. It should run just fine. The stable branch still has a dependency for `libgmp`, but that was also dropped on develop already.