# Is it ok to install ethereum and ethereum classic geth together on a server

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I already have geth of [ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) running on my amazon linux server. Can I install [ethereum classic](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/) geth on the same server.? Will it cause problem like transfering from ETH to ETC address accidentally ?  Or may be some collision since both uses geth and one geth hinder the other from running ? Are these just my fears ? do i need two separate servers ?

If both can be installed on same server, can you provide a link for installing ETC geth on Linux server?

UPDATE:

I want to interact with both ethereum nodes from a php script via json rpc.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your question only partially.

> Can I install ethereum classic geth on the same server?

Running in parallel is not a problem at all. Ideally you will setup a separate OS user for each instance to avoid accidental collisions. Moreover, if necessary, you can also use separate binaries for geth.

Comment: What does `use separate binaries for geth.` mean ?

Comment: You don't have to install the geth binary globally for all users. Each user could run a different version if necessary.

Comment: I am totally new to cryptocurencies. I installed geth as said in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/how-can-i-install-go-ethereum-on-centos

Comment: I tried installing  geth by extracting from here https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/releases
When i run geth help from the directory containing geth file. It shows command not fund..?

Comment: Do you have at least basic Linux/Unix skills? If not, I would recommend, you start learning that first.

Comment: `The simplest way to get started running a node is to visit our Releases page and download a zipped executable binary (matching your operating system, of course), then moving the unzipped file geth to somewhere in your $PATH. Now you should be able to open a terminal and run $ geth help to make sure it's working.`
https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/

Comment: Just a wild guess: did you try ./geth ?